# elements are in panel, but not accessible from js or console

Tags: javascript, dom, developer-tools

I'm working on one site,

1. when trying to access elements of developer console or js returns null.

[image]

2. from the elements panel, the element is exactly there.

[image]

but if I copied the js path from the elements panel to the console it works.

1. from elements panel:

[image]

2. to the console:

[image]

The site uses angular (I guess,) and I'm creating a script to do some changes on it.

first-time such a thing happens to me,  what's the reason?

Comment: site is: https://www.bovada.lv/sports/football/nfl/cleveland-browns-pittsburgh-steelers-202101102015

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I don't own the website, and the problem does not include code, only document. querySelector which returns null

Comment: Fine but we can't even copy the code you are trying to run in console since it is in image

Comment: Where are you planning on running the production code? UserScript, extension , headless browser ,  console?

Comment: it's an extension, but even in the deveoper tools it's not working.. I guess it has something to do with the domShadow and security practices, but I want to know what's exactly happening here. did you check the website?

Comment: No. Don't feel like recreating your code from image since you aren't willing to provide it in text

Comment: code is: ` document.querySelector('#widgets') ` it's returning `null` from content-script or developer tools. but when you manually copy the js path from elements panel it becomes available